# insufficient network error blackberry simulator

Tags: blackberry, java-me, blackberry-simulator, blackberry-maps

I am trying to make an app for blackberry to do somethink on blackberry maps. When I start debugging on smilator it gives an error as insufficient network coverage.

I tried google.com on it's browser and it worked! But on my app it gives insufficient network error.

How this problem can be solved ?

Answer (score 5):

I see two reasons for this problem.

1. Perhaps your simulator has "Low network coverage" setting set. Check BB Simulator options.
2. Most probably you forgot to launch MDS Simulator too. To provide internet access to BlackBerry simulator, launch MDS Simulator.